# Why is the error handling for IEnumerator.Current different from IEnumerator<T>.Current?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I would have thought that executing the following code for an empty collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>` would throw an exception:

```
var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
var type = enumerator.Current.GetType(); // Surely should throw?
```

Because the collection is empty, then accessing `IEnumerator.Current` is invalid, and I would have expected an exception. However, no exception is thrown for `List<T>`.

This is allowed by [the documentation for `IEnumerator<T>.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which states that `Current` is undefined under any of the following conditions:

- The enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection, immediately after the enumerator is created. MoveNext must be called to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.
- The last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of
  the collection.
- The enumerator is invalidated due to changes made in the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements.

(I'm assuming that "fails to throw an exception" can be categorised as "undefined behaviour"...)

However, if you do the same thing but use an `IEnumerable` instead, you DO get an exception. This behaviour is specified by [the documentation for `IEnumerator.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which states:

- Current should throw an InvalidOperationException if the last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of the collection.

**My question is: Why this difference? Is there a good technical reason that I'm unaware of?**

It means identical-seeming code can behave very differently depending on whether it's using `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`, as the following program demonstrates (note how the code inside `showElementType1()` and `showElementType1()` is identical):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<int>();

            showElementType1(list); // Does not throw an exception.
            showElementType2(list); // Throws an exception.
        }

        private static void showElementType1(IEnumerable<int> collection)
        {
            var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            var type = enumerator.Current.GetType(); // No exception thrown here.
            Console.WriteLine(type);
        }

        private static void showElementType2(IEnumerable collection)
        {
            var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            var type = enumerator.Current.GetType(); // InvalidOperationException thrown here.
            Console.WriteLine(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but in first case - T - _int_ that can't be _null_, so no exception, but in second - Curretn is object, so default is _null_

Comment: I've been writing this as an answer, but it doesn't really feel good enough, so... Performance - generic collections have been designed with fixing the huge performance issues of boxing value types in a list (among other reasons, of course). Checking for `hasValue` on each `Current` access doesn't sound like a lot, but consider that LINQ also came at that time - using enumerators *heavily*, even for things that used to be simple array iterations. You're supposed to check `MoveNext` anyway, so it doesn't hurt much to allow `Current` to be arbitrary when `MoveNext` returns `false`.

Comment: in source for `List<T>`: [current = default(T);](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1196)

Comment: @Grundy It happens whether it's a reference type or not, so that's nothing to do with it. You can change my sample code to `List<string>` and the same thing happens.

Comment: @Grundy While that's true, the `IEnumerable` case doesn't throw `NullReferenceException` - it throws `InvalidOperationException`. It explicitly checks whether the last `MoveNext` (if any) returned `false` or not.

Comment: @Luaan, interesting that for generic: [`just return current`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1233) but for non generic: [added range checking](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1239)

Comment: @Grundy Yup, I've checked that as well. But the determining factor is the `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>` contracts, respectively. The `IEnumerator<T>` is less strict, so `List<T>` can *afford* to omit the check for the typed enumerator. Since typed enumerators were introduced along with LINQ (which meant a huge increase in using enumerators), this is entirely reasonable. The old `IEnumerator` contract is still there for backwards compatibility, and works the same as before.

Comment: Yet another side-effect of the chronically leaky abstraction of value types.  It's not like the framework couldn't check this, the code to do so is just far too expensive to be added to every use of Current.

Comment: @Luuan Indeed - it looks like they deliberately relaxed the constraints for `IEnumerable<T>` because they wanted to increase performance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem with `IEnumerable<T>` is that `Current` is of type `T`. Instead of throwing an exception, [`default(T)` is returned](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1229) (it is set from `MoveNextRare`).

When using `IEnumerable` you don't have the type, and you can't return a default value.

The actual problem is you don't check the return value of `MoveNext`. If it returns `false`, you shouldn't call `Current`. The exception is okay. I think they found it more convenient to return `default(T)` in the `IEnumerable<T>` case.

Exception handling brings overhead, returning `default(T)` doesn't (that much). Maybe they just thought there was nothing useful to return from the `Current` property in the case of `IEnumerable` (they don't know the type). That problem is 'solved' in `IEnumerable<T>` when using `default(T)`.

According to this [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806924/iterator-blocks-are-not-implemented-according-to-documentation) (thanks [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) for commenting):

> For performance reasons the Current property of generated Enumerators is kept extremely simple - it simply returns the value of the generated 'current' backing field.

This could point in the direction of the overhead of exception handling. Or the required extra step to validate the value of `current`.

They effectively just wave the responsibility to `foreach`, since that is the main user of the enumerator:

> The *vast* majority of interactions with enumerators are in the form of foreach loops which already guard against accessing current in either of these states so it would be wasteful to burn extra CPU cycles for every iteration to check for these states that almost no one will ever encounter.

Comment: I don't think it being more convenient to return `default(T)` is the answer. Surely it's just as easy (and more informative to the caller) to throw an exception? My question is really, why would they choose to cover-up an error?

Comment: Well, exception handling brings overhead, returning `default(T)` doesn't. Maybe they just thought there was nothing useful to return from the `Current` property. That problem is 'solved' when using `default(T)`.

Comment: See [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806924/iterator-blocks-are-not-implemented-according-to-documentation): `For performance reasons the Current property of generated Enumerators is kept extremely simple - it simply returns the value of the generated 'current' backing field.`.

Comment: But why generic `Current` do not throw exception?

Comment: @JesseGood that is the actual answer to this question :)

Comment: @JesseGood: Good one. So performance could point to exception handling overhead?

Comment: But not throwing an exception means that invalid code will incorrectly execute!

Comment: @PatrickHofman Unlikely. Instead, it's the extra check needed - the `IEnumerator.Current` code has to do extra bounds checks, on each `Current` evaluation. The `IEnumerator<T>` simply returns a field value.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: But if it is documented you should check the return value, who is wrong?

Comment: Actually strange solution by MS. I think assigning default value is unnecessary overhead. Throwing exception in Current will be overhead only if someone didn't check result of `MoveNext`. Well.. we will have to check some condition each time we access current.

Comment: While the interface of `IEnumerable` doesn't have a type, any given implementation does. It would be just as possible to have `Current` return the default value of that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think that extra checking is good if you can do it. Otherwise why do we validate method arguments and throw ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions, and so on?

Comment: I think we're overlooking one thing. The use of `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` explicitly should be a rather *rare thing* to do. This is way `foreach` was provided, so we don't have to deal with these kind of nasty of by one (although documented) behavior.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Indeed. That is what I have just added from the linked post.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Actually, you can see that the enumerator implementation for list doesn't check anything for `IEnumerable<T>.Current` - it simply returns the value of a local field. The result is *undefined* when `MoveNext` returns `false` - in practice, this means that if there's no elements in the list, the result of `Current` is `default(T)`, but otherwise, it's the *last* element. It's a pretty simple and effective optimization - `MoveNext` does the exact same check anyway, so why do it twice?

Comment: I really don't think they avoided throwing an exception because of extra overhead of an exception. They could have done that for the non-generic version too, but they throw an exception for that. I can see @JesseGood 's answer, and that seems to be the actual reason - they want `.Current` to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: See the last part of my answer with another part of the linked post that explains the 'performance' they were tuning.

Comment: Yes, I agree - the answer would appear to be "For performance reasons". I guess for something as fundamental as iterating over a collection, performance >> guaranteed correctness.

Answer (score 4):

To better match how people tend to implement it in practice. As is the change of wording from "Current also throws an exception …" in previous versions of the documentation to "Current should throw …" in the current version.

Depending on how the implementation is working, throwing an exception might be quite a bit of work, and yet because of how `Current` is used in conjunction with `MoveNext()` then that exceptional state is hardly ever going to come up. This is all the more so when we consider that the vast majority of uses are compiler-generated and don't actually have scope for a bug where `Current` is called before `MoveNext()` or after it has returned `false` to ever happen. With normal use we can expect the case to never come up.

So if you are writing an implementation of `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` where catching the error condition is tricky, you might well decide not to do so. And if you do make that decision, it probably isn't going to cause you any problems. Yes, you broke the rules, but it probably didn't matter.

And since it won't cause any problems except for someone who **uses** the interface in a buggy way, documenting it as undefined behaviour moves the burden from the implementer to the caller to not do something the caller shouldn't be doing in the first place.

But all that said, since `IEnumerable.Current` is still documented as "should throw `InvalidOperationException` for backwards compatibility and since doing so would match the "undefined" behaviour of `IEnumerable<T>.Current`, the probably the best way to perfectly fulfil the documented behaviour of the interface is to have `IEnumerable<T>.Current` throw an `InvalidOperationException` in such cases, and have `IEnumerable.Current` just call into that.

In a way this is the opposite to the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` also inherits from `IDisposable`. The compiler-generated uses of `IEnumerable` will check if the implementation also implements `IDisposable` and call `Dispose()` if it does, but aside from the slight performance overhead of that test it meant that both implementers and hand-coded callers would sometimes forget about that, and not implement or call `Dispose()` when they should. Forcing all implementations to have at least an empty `Dispose()` made life easier for people in the opposite way to just having `Current` have undefined behaviour when it isn't valid.

If there were no backwards compatibility issues then we would probably have `Current` documented as undefined in such cases for both interfaces, and both interfaces inheriting from `IDisposable`. We probably also wouldn't have `Reset()` which is nothing but a nuisance.